# Transform animation bug in swift?

Tags: uiview, swift, core-animation, transform, calayer

Here is two code for objective c and swift, both are the same. 
Using objective c it animate scale correctly, but in swift it just jump to final value, i think this is a bug, can someone test and verify it?

Objective C

```
    UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)];
    testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self addSubview:testView];

    CAKeyframeAnimation * transformAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    transformAnim.values                = @[[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * M_PI/180, 0, 0, -1)],
                                            [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1), CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * M_PI/180, 0, 0, 1))],
                                            [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1)],
                                            [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1), CATransform3DMakeRotation(-8 * M_PI/180, 0, 0, 1))]];
    transformAnim.keyTimes              = @[@0, @0.349, @0.618, @1];
    transformAnim.duration              = 1;
    [testView.layer addAnimation:transformAnim forKey:@"test"];
```

Swift

```
        let testView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100))
        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.addSubview(testView)

        var transformAnim            = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath:"transform")
        transformAnim.values         = [NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * CGFloat(M_PI/180), 0, 0, -1)),
            NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1), CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * CGFloat(M_PI/180), 0, 0, 1))),
            NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1)),
            NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1), CATransform3DMakeRotation(-8 * CGFloat(M_PI/180), 0, 0, 1)))]
        transformAnim.keyTimes       = [0, 0.349, 0.618, 1]
        transformAnim.duration       = 1

        testView.layer.addAnimation(transformAnim, forKey: "transform")
```

This is objc anim, it works as intended

[image: objc transform anim]
This is swift anim, scale transform just jump
[image: swift transform anim]

Comment: what is the animation supposed to do?  I want to make sure what I play with goes in the right direction.

Comment: @MinnesotaSteve Its supposed to animate the view bigger, and animate rotation. It works fine using objc, but in swift the rotation animate fine, however it just jump to final scale without animation

Comment: Okay, +1 for making nice gif animations to illustrate the problem! :)

Comment: Have you got _any_ other code in this project that might be affecting this? Try testing where the _only_ code is the code I provided.

Comment: Unable to reproduce based on the information given. Voting to close the question on that basis.

Comment: worked as your gif for me after commenting out //  self.addSubview(testView)

Answer (score 5):

I tested your code in both Objective-C and Swift and the behavior was exactly the same in both languages (it looks like your *first* gif animation in both cases).

[image]

Here's how to confirm my results. Your code didn't make sense to me (add a view and animate it all in one move?) so I broke it up into two button methods, and I moved it into the view controller. So, here it is in Objective-C:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) UIView* testView;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (IBAction) doButton1 {
    UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)];
    testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:testView];
    self.testView = testView;
}
- (IBAction) doButton2 {
    CAKeyframeAnimation * transformAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    transformAnim.values                = @[[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * M_PI/180, 0, 0, -1)],
                                            [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1), CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * M_PI/180, 0, 0, 1))],
                                            [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1)],
                                            [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1), CATransform3DMakeRotation(-8 * M_PI/180, 0, 0, 1))]];
    transformAnim.keyTimes              = @[@0, @0.349, @0.618, @1];
    transformAnim.duration              = 1;
    [self.testView.layer addAnimation:transformAnim forKey:@"test"];
}
@end
```

And here it is in Swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var testView : UIView!

    @IBAction func doButton1() {
        let testView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100))
        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.view.addSubview(testView)
        self.testView = testView
    }
    @IBAction func doButton2() {
        var transformAnim            = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath:"transform")
        transformAnim.values         = [NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * CGFloat(M_PI/180), 0, 0, -1)),
            NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1), CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * CGFloat(M_PI/180), 0, 0, 1))),
            NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1)),
            NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1), CATransform3DMakeRotation(-8 * CGFloat(M_PI/180), 0, 0, 1)))]
        transformAnim.keyTimes       = [0, 0.349, 0.618, 1]
        transformAnim.duration       = 1
        self.testView.layer.addAnimation(transformAnim, forKey: "transform")
    }
}
```

Now, in either language, tap the first button (to add the view) and then the second button (to animate it).

Comment: I've updated my question with gif images,
I've copied your code for Swift, but the scale still jumps, I wonder what the problem?

Comment: In my tests it jumps _at the end_ when the animation is finished, but that makes perfect sense and it does it in both languages.

Comment: What system are you testing in? iOS 7 or iOS 8?

Comment: Scratch that - I tried both iOS 7 and iOS 8 and it's smooth in both.

Comment: I test it on iOS 8, I think swift only for iOS 8 isn't it.

What Xcode version you use? I'm using Xcode 6.0 release

Comment: I've tried only include scale transform only but the same bugs still occurred.

It seems the bug only when using CAKeyframeAnimation and when key times set. If it is not set it works correctly.

Comment: All I did was copy and paste _your_ code - I didn't type any code of my own. But I can't reproduce the behavior shown in your "bad" animation. It looks like your "good" animation.

Comment: I am using Xcode 6.1 (current beta, designated as GM) with iOS 8.1. You might try that, since that's the only difference between what we're doing as far as I can tell. I hope that turns out to be the solution!

Comment: Ok, I think I should try new Xcode, thanks for your help and suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to put

```
 self.targetView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Before calling the animation.

```
 testView.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1),      CATransform3DMakeRotation(-8 * CGFloat(M_PI/180), 0, 0, 1))
    testView.layer.addAnimation(transformAnim, forKey: "transform")
```

It works fine

Comment: is it on viewDidAppear ?

Comment: Ok i got. Just put the latest value on your list, before calling animation

Comment: Thats what I do previously, layoutIfNeeded() before start anim. Nope its not in viewDidAppear.

Comment: 1) You would want to put there 2) Before calling animation, set the last transform value to your layer, I checked, it works as excepted and does not jump. Please, check the update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to this answer, but I just noticed this bug too. In Swift, it seems as if you can't add a subview immediately before animating it. It seems as if you have to insert a delay, ex:

```
    let testView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100))
    testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    self.addSubview(testView)

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: "animate", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func animate() {
    var transformAnim            = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath:"transform")
    transformAnim.values         = [NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * CGFloat(M_PI/180), 0, 0, -1)),
        NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1), CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * CGFloat(M_PI/180), 0, 0, 1))),
        NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1)),
        NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1), CATransform3DMakeRotation(-8 * CGFloat(M_PI/180), 0, 0, 1)))]
    transformAnim.keyTimes       = [0, 0.349, 0.618, 1]
    transformAnim.duration       = 1

    testView.layer.addAnimation(transformAnim, forKey: "transform")
}
```